# React Native Maps: Is it impossible to draw a route between two locations without paying?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-api, react-native-maps, google-directions-api

I need to draw a driving route between a vehicle and a destination in my React Native app. I've been looking for solutions, and the most straightforward is [this guide](https://github.com/bramus/react-native-maps-directions). This uses the `Google Directions` API, and it looks as though you have to set up a billing account and they charge you for every query.

**What I Want To Know:**

1) Is it the case that there's no way to draw a driving route between two locations in `React Native Maps` without having to pay for it?

2) Assuming I do use the `Google Directions API`, [this doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/usage-and-billing) talks about how much you're charged per query. If I were re-calculating the user's position and route between position and destination every 10 seconds, would that calculation be one query?